# jQuery multiple target IDs for click function

Tags: jquery, selector

This may be a little redundant but I was wondering if there's a way to improve the code by shortening it to avoid repetition.

```
$('a[href*="#about"]').click(function()
```

I want to target `#about` `#products` `#process` `#gallery` `#contact`

I want to avoid:

```
$('a[href*="#about"]', 'a[href*="#process"]', a[href*="#etc"]' ).click(function()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give them all a class and target that:

```
$(".the-class").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

If you can't do that, then what you want to avoid (but done correctly) is what you need to do:

```
$("[href=#about], [href=#products], [href=#process], [href=#gallery], [href=#contact]").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I'm using them as anchors for smooth scrolling, my understanding is that you can't use classes as anchors.

Comment: @Dotol: You can *add* classes to `a` elements, while leaving their `href`s in place as well, and target the class for your click handler. E.g., `<a href="#products" class="smooth">...</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can set up a single click handler on the page, and delegate based on which element was clicked.

```
var handledHrefs = ['#about', '#products', '#process', '#gallery', '#contact'];
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function (e) {
  if (handledHrefs.includes(e.target.attr('href'))) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

This actually has a better performance than attaching individual event handlers, surprisingly enough.